# Is there a way to use AWS's sam build with OpenTofu?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws, opentofu

I'm trying to run and debug a lambda function locally using the AWS CLI and OpenTofu. Using `sam build --hook-name terraform` [works great](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-aws-sam-cli-and-hashicorp-terraform/). However, now that [Terraform is no longer open-source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/15nt2cb/terraform_is_no_longer_open_source/), I'd like to migrate to [OpenTofu](https://opentofu.org/). Is there a way to use `sam build` with an OpenTofu hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OpenTofu is backwards-compatible with Terraform, create a symbolic link for Terraform that is actually OpenTofu.

Note: you may need to use `sudo`.

```bash
$ which tofu
/usr/local/bin/tofu

$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/tofu /usr/local/bin/terraform
```

Another option is to install Terraform locally and use Terraform for `sam build`.

If you are only looking to debug a TypeScript lambda locally with VSCode, follow [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/serverless-apps-run-debug-no-template.html).